# How to change the position of the overflow menu in Android

Tags: java, android

How can I change the position of the overflow menu?

This is the menu.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  >
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_fill"
    android:orderInCategory="101"
    android:title="@string/menu_auto_fill"
    android:showAsAction="never" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_delete_all"
    android:orderInCategory="102"
    android:title="@string/menu_remove_all"
    android:showAsAction="never" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_next"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_next_item"
    android:title="@string/menu_continue"        
    android:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

Currently the menu looks like this:

[image]

I need it to look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a submenu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  >
<item
    android:id="@+id/overflow"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_overflow"
    android:title="@string/overflow"
    android:showAsAction="always">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_fill"
            android:title="@string/menu_auto_fill" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_delete_all"
            android:title="@string/menu_remove_all" />
    </menu>

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_next"
    android:orderInCategory="101"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_next_item"
    android:title="@string/menu_continue"        
    android:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

Note that this requires you to define the overflow item, with his own icon and so on.

Comment: This also lets you manage all the actions from the onOptionsItemSelected() method, which a PopupMenu - I think - does not.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change the position of a the designated android overflow menu item, However you could mimic the overflow menu item by placing a similar icon to the left of the rightarrow icon in the action bar and displaying a [PopupMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html) on its click, which seems to suite your need.

Read more about implementing a PopupMenu [here](http://www.javatpoint.com/android-popup-menu-example)

Comment: Thanks. I accepted the above solutions, because it's simpler and no additional code is required.

Comment: @kirilv That seems apt, but in case you wish to have dynamic options this is the way to go.